# Starting MySQL in a PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, windows

I need to start MySQL with a PHP script. So I have:

```
system("C:\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.8\bin\mysqld");
```

I have tried this on two computers, running Windows 7 and Windows XP. When I try this by typing this in the command line, both hang, although this is starting MySQL. How do I get MySQL to start with out it hanging my script up, which then in turn is freezing up my page?

Comment: Have you tried placing a short cut to the mysql exe file into the "Startup" folder in you computer? start -> Startup

Comment: Why do you want to start MySQL through a PHP script?

Comment: That works for me, however, that requires that you be logged in as the administrator, which may not always be the case. This is for an intranet, and each computer will have an instance of mysql on it. And most will be logging into the computer as lower level users.

Comment: RTLM: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/windows-start-service.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try running the command asynchronously, which will prevent the browser from freezing. It can be done by calling shell_exec and adding an ampersand ("&") at the end of the command. Example:

```
shell_exec("C:\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.8\bin\mysqld &");
```

Comment: Not to mention that the string is double-quoted; this can't work.

Comment: Why would double quoting have any effect on this?